# Loading products to galleries in the desired order

Tags: 7

I have some menu choices that open specific galleries. I have now created a new gallery called Women and linked my Women products to in (in product edit mode) in the order I desired. Drupal does not obey this ordering and I am not sure what the default ordering is ...and can't change it either? anyone know how what happens here because I wanted my own products to appear first in this gallery? I'm on Drupal 7.35

Comment: Can you provide more information about what modules/libraries you are using?

Comment: A "gallery" in Drupal is not a set thing so you will have to explain houw you have configured your gallery. For example, is it a node with a multi value image field or is each image a node or do you just use file entities and no nodes or something else?